# Dynamic form submit reloads the page instead of calling ngSubmit function

Tags: javascript, angular8, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I am trying to submit form dynamically from ts file.

Form

```html
<form [formGroup]="mainForm" #mainFormEle (Submit)="doNothing()">
.....
</form>
```

and the ts

```js
  @ViewChild('mainFormEle',{static:false}) mainFormEle

  doNothing(){
    ..
    console.log('came in')
    ..
  }

  mainFunc(){
    ..
    this.mainFormEle.nativeElement.submit()
    ..
  }
```

But the above block reloads the page on submit. And never goes into doNothing(). Also tried with (ngSubmit) and (onSubmit)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved that issue by invoking ***requestSubmit()*** insted of ***submit()***

[MDN - HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you have a `button` within that form. For it not to trigger the native action of submitting the form. You have to explicitly add `type="button" on the button.

e.g.

```html
<button type="button">
  <!-- rest of the button -->
</button>
```

Comment: Still reloads the page on submit. But It works when a submit button introduced to the form and trigger click event on the button, to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

1. Introduced a submit button.
2. Instead of submitting the form from ts, Just triggered the click event on the button.

```html
<button type="submit" #submitButton></button>
```

or

```html
<button type="submit" hidden #submitButton></button>
```

```js
@ViewChild('submitButton',{static:false}) submitButton

  doNothing(){
    ..
    console.log('came in')
    ..
  }

  mainFunc(){
    ..
    this.submitButton.nativeElement.click()
    ..
  }
```

And now it works.